# Application Support to Internet explorer 6 and 8

Tags: jsf, netbeans, internet-explorer-8, richfaces, internet-explorer-6

I have successfully developed some application using netbeans as IDE. and they are all in currently production for the company.
But, here I faced one problem that the application is running perfectly fine in IE-6, but when i upgraded it to the IE-8, It does not support full features of the application and it is behaving awkward.

So I wanted to know, how 2 versions of IE makes the same application behaving different, and Is it related to some kind of development of the application, and whether we can make it working in all the versions.

I want to know some behind the scenes fact.
Thanks!!

Comment: IE6/7 are the worst webbrowsers the world ever has seen. FireFox, Chrome, Safari, Opera, etc follow web standards whereas IE6/7 do not. You should test your webapps in them as well, or in IE8+. Then, test again in IE6/7 and fix issues individually with IE6/7 specific CSS/JS hacks.

Comment: actually I had started the development with IE6 only, and it worked fine, but later when I upgraded it to IE8, It was not supporting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using richfaces 3.x, it has known issues with IE9 which are not yet fixed.

If you application work with IE7, then specify [`X-UI-Compatible`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) meta tag to emulate IE7 behavior.

Comment: That's okk dear, but first i wnt to know what is the main concern for it...like u told bug issues.

Comment: Different versions of IE have different assumptions about doctype and some rendering engine issues are fixed in the newer versions of IE. To be honest IE before version 8 was very poor in CSS support and your CSS assumptions in your code which was tested agains IE6 may not be correct. You should show us your code so that we can help you what's the main issue. But generally speaking it's about your doctype. Try adding a transitive doctype at the beginning of your HTML and see the result in different IEs. You can use IETester to have different versions of IE on one machine

Comment: what code u want to see i mean in which type of file..., as i dont know what code exactly creating this problem...